# About shopping questions

Tags: feature-request, moderation

My question

[Is this website that claims to provide paper writing services real and legal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151720/is-this-website-that-claims-to-provide-paper-writing-services-real-and-legal/151721)

was (rightly) closed as shopping question (I'm a dumb newbie in Academics SE).

I'm **not** interested in reopening the question: I've accepted the (excellent) answer.

A (IMHO) reasonable suggestion: the check-questions-bot can warn "Your link [...] shopping question. See [...] Edit if required."

Editing out the linked website was surely a *necessary* action. But...

An (admittedly) twisted question: it was *sufficient*? Many similar/cloned web sites can be found googling some of the quoted phrases. Ditto for a Google Images search of the posted image.

Comment: What is the check-answers-bot?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, all the questions pass a little test before being accepted. V. gr.: if the question has zero tags, the check-questions-bot (my name) can say "add 1 to 5 tags".

Comment: @GoodDeeds, see mi correction.

Comment: The bot is site-wide (across SO and all of SE). Academia.SE is tiny by comparison, and the shopping question ban is specific to Academia.SE. It's very unlikely the company would put dev time into this for just one small site; it's likely not a trivial task to detect shopping questions, and even though we've closed a lot of them I doubt we have a sufficient sample to train an AI to do the check without a substantial error rate.

Comment: @BryanKrause, thanks for the information.

Answer (score -1):

No.  This question is a shopping question because it asks for an evaluation of a service.  Hiding the identity of the service does not change that.

Comment: Re: "Hiding the identity". Then, what does "[...] edit your question to ask how to make your choice *in general and without naming any particular options*." **mean**?

Comment: Re: "valuation of a service". Actually, I am utterly skeptic *even* about the *existence* of the service. Self-quote  «("ethics" !!!!!) suggests that the site is a parody...».

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Scammers do not wish to target intelligent people.  An example of a potentially on-topic, (but unwise) question is "How do I identify a high quality ghost writing service so that I can commit fraud effectively?" whereas your question seems to be "Is this particular ghostwriting service an effective way to commit fraud?"

Comment: Since you're not planning on committing fraud, please don't ask about it.

Comment: "Since you're not planning on committing fraud, please don't ask about it." OK, but... I *sincerely* believe that the *answer* by Captain Emacs can be *useful* for dumb-and-lazy students and dumb senior lecturers (like me).

Comment: I think the question you want is "What should instructors do to reduce paid cheating?" or maybe "What is paid cheating?"

Comment: "contract cheating" is the correct term, I think